# getting the index path of a cell inside UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

could anyone tell me how to get the index of a cell inside its class which is uitableViewCell more specifically , inside an action function of UISwitch .
I did the following..

```
        var cell = sender.superview?.superview as UITableViewCell
        var table: UITableView = cell.superview as UITableView
        let indexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)
```

but then it crashes.
what is the solution ?

Comment: What line does it crash on?  What does the error say?

Comment: it says : "Swift dynamic cast failed". If I just write the first line which is casting to the uitableVewCell, it crashes.
even if I write { var cell = sender.superview as UITableViewCell }
it also crashes

Comment: You should NOT be doing this, a cell should have no business knowing what index it is inside of the tableView. If somehow this were to work though, you'd want to pass "self" for into the tableView method from the cell.

Comment: When configuring the cell in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` configure a closure to be used as the action when the switch is invoked. [Read this](http://mikeabdullah.net/thl-diary-19.1.html)

Comment: @JMFR and then , how can I call this closure from the custom cell class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Assuming you have a `UISwitch *cellSwitch` object in `cell` custom class

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.cellSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
```

In `IBAction` for this switch:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
```

Comment: Isn't cellForRowAtIndexPath a UITableView function?
how can I use it without making a reference to the tableView?
I didn't get your point.

Comment: I could explain if u add your cellForRowAtIndexPath method here

Comment: Make sure that you are always casting to your custom cell class not UITableViewCell if you have custom cell.  @Nishant solution is best way to go. Clean approach.

Comment: @Nishant could write the code in detail please? I haven't understood u yet. :/

Comment: @يعربالمصطفى: As i said, I could explain in detail if u add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method here

Comment: Do u want me to add it as a comment here?!!

Comment: ohhh sorry @Nishant , I finally understood u, I mixed between cellForRowAtIndexPath normal function and the other one that returns the index of a certain cell in a table. thank u so much I used your solution and it is working now . :)

Comment: @يعربالمصطفى: Great! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to know the index path of the cell inside of the cell. The index path is an implementation detail of the UITableViewController. The cell should be an independent object.

What you really want to do is to assign an action to run when your switch is changed.

```
class MySwitchCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var switchCellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!

    //Declare an action to be run
    var action: ((sender: UISwitch) -> Void)?
    //then run it
    @IBAction func switchAction(sender: UISwitch) {
        action?(sender: sender)
    }

}
```

Then give the action something to do when you configure the cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SwitchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MySwitchCell

        cell.switchCellLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.mySwitch.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(items[indexPath.row])
        cell.action = { [weak self] sender in
            if let tableViewController = self {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(sender.on, forKey: tableViewController.items[indexPath.row]) }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

For example this one sets a bool in the NSUserDefaults based on the state of that switch.

You can checkout the whole sample project from https://github.com/regnerjr/SimpleCellSwitchAction